# org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: junit, hsqldb

Stack trace: WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -5501, SQLState: 42501
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - user lacks privilege or object not found: TEST_CASE

My applicationContext-junit-test.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    
            <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false">
            </property>
            <property name="driverClassName">
                <value>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</value>
            </property>
            <property name="url">
                <value>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testcasedb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;</value>
            </property>
            <property name="username">
                <value>sa</value>
            </property>
            <property name="password">
                <value></value>
            </property>
    
        </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    
                    <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop> -->
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.org.team.testcaseapi.dto.request.TestCase</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

TestCase.java file:


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "test_case", schema = "testcase")
    @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    @XmlRootElement
    public class TestCase implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
        private Long Id;
    
        public Long getId() {
            return Id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            Id = id;
        }
    }

**DBUtil.java** runs the DDL and DML hsql files and DB is created successfully(I have printed DB on console).

      public class DBUtil {
                public static void createTestSchema() {
                    String sqlPath = "src/test/resources/sql";
                        ApplicationContext dbCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-junit-test.xml");
                BasicDataSource ds = dbCtx.getBean(BasicDataSource.class);
                Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
                        Statement st = null;
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Creating Schema !");
                        File dir = new File(sqlPath);
                        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
                        SqlFile sqlFile;
                        for (File file : files) {
                                sqlFile = new SqlFile(file);
                                sqlFile.setConnection(conn);
                                sqlFile.execute();
                            }
                        }
    }
```

**DaoImpl.java**
My HQL query fetches the zero results( if I set hbm2ddl.auto as "create")
My HQL query throws JDBCExceptionReporter:user lacks privilege or object not found( if I dont use hbm2ddl.auto property)

```
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void getAllData(){

        String hql = "FROM TestCase";
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<TestCase> results;
        try {
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            results = query.list();  // list is empty : []
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From TestCase.java

I removed schema in the @Table and it worked. Also I removed Create Schema in DDL and similar references.

So updated TestCase.java will look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_case")
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@XmlRootElement
public class TestCase implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long Id;

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database URL properties are wrong for a memory database. Correct use of properties for a file: and mem: database are as follows:

```
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:hsqldb:file:testcasedb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;</value>

    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testcasedb</value>
```

If you use shutdown=true with a mem: database all data is erased as soon as the last open connection closes. With a file database, all data is saved.

Comment: Hi Fredt, I removed shutdown and write_delay but still getting the ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - user lacks privilege or object not found: TEST_CASE